# Complex mix of licenses for stand-alone installer, and the softwares it installs

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, lgpl, redistribution

I'm writing an installer for some softwares, and wish to make the installer stand-alone, i.e. everything baked into a single executable.

One of the softwares that are installed has GPL 3, built from un-modified sources. The other softwares have a different license which allows them to be redistributed like this, without the need to make the source-code available.

The installer itself uses the [Qt framework](http://qt.io/) licensed under LGPL 3, and has to be statically linked since it will be a stand-alone installer.

Am I correct in thinking that the softwares and the installer are each and all separate issues, and thus that the only things required of me is that I make the installer LGPL 3, and include a written offer of the source-codes of the installer and the GPL 3 software?

Comment: The keywords you are looking for is "mere aggregation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would almost certainly be correct. The last paragraph of section 5 of the GPLv3 (applicable in this case because the LGPLv3 incorporates the GPLv3 by reference and then modifies it) covers this sort of situation where several works are aggregated without interacting.